# blur() google map to not hear key events

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a google map and a scrolling div to the right of it. The problem I have is that if somebody clicks and drags the map around and then moves to the scrolling div and pushes a down arrow, or pgdn, or something like that, then the google map moves as well.

I DO NOT want to disable keyboard input in the map, I want to leave it enabled, but I want to find a way that when the users hovers the scrolling div on the right that I can fire some sort of blur() event on something that will take the focus off of the map so that it won't 'hear' keyboard input.

This works if I click outside of the map canvas, but I've tried calling blur() on all kinds of map canvas elements when the user hovers over the div to the right with no luck.

Has anybody come across a similar problem (and hopefully solution)?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved half of your problem, if I interpreted it correctly in the first place. I'm assuming the behavior you want is, when your mouse is outside to map, for the keypresses to move the scrolling div up and down? Otherwise, what I wrote might work (:

Since I can't force a click in the scrolling div, the hack I came up with was to insert an invisible text input and make the script click inside this text box. That stops the keypresses affecting the map, but we don't get the scrollbar moving either. I am concerned in older browsers, this click event will automatically scroll the div to where the text box is located. Depends on your page, but I think it's a better idea to keep its position fixed, like below the map.

http://jsfiddle.net/xNT96/2/

I just tried it in Chrome (key presses do nothing after mouseout), and Firefox (if scrolling was clicked on, when there's a mouseout the scrolling div will move with key presses). Even clicking on the div is inconsistent. So it's far from an ideal solution but hope I gave you some ideas :(